# Why are the sensu metrics not directly shown in Graphite?

Tags: graphite, sensu

It takes around 15 minutes, before metrics sent by Sensu appear in Graphite.

**Questions**

- Why does it take 15 minutes?
- Is it possible to accelerate this?

**Discussion**

Although a retention of 1 minute has been configured:

*/opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf*

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d
```

and both the sensu-client:

*/var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log*

```
{"timestamp":"2016-08-16T23:17:54.131805+0000","level":"info","message":
"publishing check result","payload":{"client":"rhel","check":{"type":"metric",
"command":"/etc/sensu/plugins/metrics-memory-percent.rb","handlers":["relay"],
"name":"load_metrics3","issued":1471389473,"interval":10,"subscribers":["ALL"],
"executed":1471389473,"duration":0.226,
"output":"box01-ubuntu.memory_percent.free 3.6590918167658453
1471389474\nbox01-ubuntu.memory_percent.buffers 0.0 1471389474\nbox01-ubuntu.memory_percent.cached 22.651064339630178 1471389474\n
box01-ubuntu.memory_percent.dirty 0.01837134070849475 1471389474\n
box01-ubuntu.memory_percent.swapUsed 7.438716420871131 1471389474\
nbox01-ubuntu.memory_percent.usedWOBuffersCaches 73.68984384360398 1471389474\nbox01-ubuntu.memory_percent.freeWOBuffersCaches 26.310156156396022 1471389474\n","status":0}}}
```

as graphite log activity:

*/opt/graphite/storage/log/carbon-cache/carbon-cache-a/creates.log*

```
16/08/2016 23:14:29 :: new metric box01-ubuntu.memory_percent.freeWOBuffersCaches 
matched schema default_1min_for_1day
```

the graph appears 15 minutes later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because the time on the sensu-server was not synchronized with the sensu-clients.